# Erro no componente VueJs, conversor de moeda

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Olá, estou tentando criar um conversor de moeda com um componente, mas estou tento problemas

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Vue JS</title>
                <script src="vue.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>

            <div id="app">
                <conversor></conversor>
            </div>

    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.js

```
 Vue.component('conversor', {
        props:{
            moedaA:{
                default:""
            },
            moedaB:{
                default:""
            },
        },
        template: ` <h2>{{moedaA}} Para {{moedaB}}</h2>
        <input type="text" v-model="moedaA_value" v-bind:placeholder="moedaA">
        <input type="button" value="Converter" v-on:click="converter">
        <h2>{{moedaB_value}}</h2>`,
    })
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
        },
    })
```

Erro:

> Error compiling template:
>
> Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are
>   using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

Comment: Coloca uma `<div>` à volta de tudo o que está dentro do `template:`. Resolve o teu problema?

Comment: Tentei fazer isso mas sem solução :/

Answer (score 1):

Como o erro já diz dentro de template deve haver exatamente um elemento pai.

Hoje você tem 4 elementos

```
<h2>{{moedaA}} Para {{moedaB}}</h2>
<input type="text" v-model="moedaA_value" v-bind:placeholder="moedaA">
<input type="button" value="Converter" v-on:click="converter">
<h2>{{moedaB_value}}</h2>
```

O correto seria:

```
<div>
   <h2>{{moedaA}} Para {{moedaB}}</h2>
   <input type="text" v-model="moedaA_value" v-bind:placeholder="moedaA">
   <input type="button" value="Converter" v-on:click="converter">
   <h2>{{moedaB_value}}</h2>
</div>
```

No seu código

```
Vue.component('conversor', {
        props:{
            moedaA:{
                default:""
            },
            moedaB:{
                default:""
            },
        },
        template: ` <div><h2>{{moedaA}} Para {{moedaB}}</h2>
        <input type="text" v-model="moedaA_value" v-bind:placeholder="moedaA">
        <input type="button" value="Converter" v-on:click="converter">
        <h2>{{moedaB_value}}</h2></div>`,
    })
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
        },
    })
```